# SQL Server .bak files - Importing to MySQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given a number of SQL Server `.bak` backup files from an old application. They would like me to import this into an online MySQL database.

What would be the best way for me to convert these to MySQL or even CSV?

I really just need the tables with data and can likely figure the relationships on my own - or with help form someone who used the old application.

I hope to avoid having to purchase any MS software.

Comment: A `.bak` file needs to be restored to a **SQL Server** instance first - then you can copy / extract / save the data and transfer it into another database system

Comment: How can I restore to a SQL instance?
Without purchasing MS software?

Comment: If the database file size is less than 10 GB, you can download and use the free SQL Server **Express** editions. If your database size is *more* than 10 GB, you're out of luck ....

Comment: The files are a few hundred MB each - less than 3G in total.
So the answer is to use "free SQL Server Express"? 
Would you know of any instruction on how to perform this operation on that software?
Care to post that as your answer and I can credit you the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.bak` file needs to be restored to a SQL Server instance first - then you can copy / extract / save the data and transfer it into another database system.

If your database size is less than 10 GB, you can use the **free** SQL Server **Express** edition provided by Microsoft to restore the `.bak` files to, and then go from there. [You can download SQL Server 2017 Express from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express).

IF you don't have a GUI tool yourself that is capable of connecting to SQL Server, you can also download the [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) - which is also free to use - and use it to work with SQL Server.

Once you have SQL Server Management Studio installed, you can easily restore your `.bak` files one by one using the wizard that opens up after you've selected `Databases > Restore Database` from the Object Explorer in SSMS:

[image]

How to work with the data once it's been restored is beyond the scope of this place - you'll find **tons** of resources out there everywhere - just find it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! :) (y)

Comment: Sorry to bother - I tried to look up what the .trn files are for - and their relationship - if any.
It seems the folders that have the .trn will restore - yet the folders that do not - will not restore and produce an error.